# Cannot read property "forEach" of undefined - Firebase and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I keep getting this error:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'forEach' of undefined

While trying to show a value from Firebase Firestore in HTML. It should show the name of the "doc.id"-user on the page, but I get the error that is shown earlier. This is my Firebase database layout: [image: Screenshot1]

[image: Screenshot2]

HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
   <ul class="friends">
   </ul>
</div>
```

Javascript code:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {

    var uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;

    var ref = firebase.firestore().collection('users').doc(uid).collection('friends');

    ref.get().then(function(querySnapshot) {

        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {

            var friends = doc.get('friends');

            if (friends === true) {
                console.log(uid, doc.id);
    
                var docRef = db.collection('users').doc(doc.id);

                docRef.get().then(snapshot => {
                    setupPosts(snapshot.docs)
                    })
                    
                    const posts = document.querySelector('.friends');
                    
                    const setupPosts = (data) => {
                    
                        let html = '';
                        data.forEach(doc => {
                            const post = doc.data();
                            const li = `
                            <li>
                                <div class="title">${post.fullname}</div>
                            </li>
                            `;
                            html += li
                        })
                    
                        posts.innerHTML = html;

                    }
                }
            })
        })
            });
```

Comment: The error is telling you you're calling a method `forEach` on an object that's undefined.  You should do some debugging to figure out which object that is, and why that object is not what you think it is.

Comment: _Which_ forEach gives you this error? `querySnapshot.forEach` or `data.forEach`?

Comment: I forgot to mention, it's the data.forEach which gives me the error!

Comment: Is `snapshot.docs` an Array? If not, I believe that's the issue, since that becomes the `data` when `data.forEach()` is called in `setupPosts()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from here:

```
var docRef = db.collection('users').doc(doc.id);

docRef.get().then(snapshot => {
    setupPosts(snapshot.docs)
})
```

The `docRef.get()` call retrieves a single document, which means that you get back a `DocumentSnapshot` object, which does not have a `forEach` method.

---

If you we're looking to load all users:

```
db.collection('users').get().then(snapshot => {
    setupPosts(snapshot.docs)
})
```

---

If you only want to load and setup one document:

```
var docRef = db.collection('users').doc(doc.id);

docRef.get().then(doc => {
    setupPosts(doc)
})
```

Comment: One problem fixed, a new one pops up! data.forEach is not a function.

Comment: If an answer fixes the problem you posted, it is custom to accept the answer and post a new question for the new problem. For the new problem: your `setupPosts` expected multiple post, so you could pass in an array of one post with `setupPosts([doc])` or create a new method `setupPost(doc)` (so for a single document).